# Can additional permissions be given to a lambda PostAuthenticate function provisioned with AWS Amplify?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

**TL;DR:** *Can Amplify CloudFormation template for a Post Authentication function configuration been manually changed to give permissions to (for example) [IoT attachPrincipalPolicy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Iot.html#attachPrincipalPolicy-property)?*

I am using AWS Amplify and the `amplify` CLI to setup a new project. Overall, Amplify has made things very easy however I am stuck with this feeling that you can only go "so far" with Amplify before things become difficult or impossible to do through an Amplify controlled project.

The use case I am interested in has to do with setting up `PubSub` with IoT - [the AWS instructions cover how to get this working](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/pubsub#aws-iot) but I would call this more "proof of concept" than "something that you should use in anything close to production" - it involves manually calling `aws iot attach-principal-policy --policy-name 'myIoTPolicy' --principal '<YOUR_COGNITO_IDENTITY_ID>'` on every single Cognito identity.

Instead what I would like to do is use a *Post Authentication* lambda function / event hook to call the [attachPrincipalPolicy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Iot.html#attachPrincipalPolicy-property) when a user logs into the website (potentially first checking to see if the policy is already attached!).

Perhaps obviously this does not "just work", I tested

```
var iot = new AWS.Iot();

  var params = {
    policyName: 'myIoTPolicy', /* required */
    principal: 'XYZ123XYZ123' /* required */
  };

  try {
    iot.attachPrincipalPolicy(params, function (err, data) {
      if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
      else console.log(data);           // successful response

      callback(null, event);
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);           // successful response
  }
```

and ended up with an error like

`AccessDeniedException: User: arn:aws:sts::123123123123123:assumed-role/project82382PostAuthentication-master/project82382PostAuthentication-master is not authorized to perform: iot:AttachPrincipalPolicy on resource: XYZ123XYZ123`

The heart of the question is, how do I give this lambda function permissions in a way that is going to not break when / if I modify the project using the Amplify CLI? For example, I could in theory change `project82382PostAuthentication-cloudformation-template.json` and add some sort of configuration that would give permission to execute `iot:AttachPrincipalPolicy`, but this would then be removed I'd think if / when I change configuration of something causing Amplify CLI to regenerate the CloudFormation templates?

Comment: Did you figure it out? Is it possible to attach a policy to IAM programmatically?

Comment: wondering the same thing...need to give my lambda execution role access to secrets manager

Answer (score 8):

Although it is quite the manual process, go to ./amplify/backend/function/your-function-name/your-function-name-cloud-formation-template.json and find "lambdaexecutionpolicy" -> "Properties" -> "PolicyDocument" -> "Statement". This is an array of policies. Simply add another object to the array with whatever you need. For example,

```
{
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Action": [
    "sns:*"
  ],
  "Resource": "*"
}
```

Then run `amplify status` and you should see a pending update to your lambda. Run `amplify push` and those changes will be deployed to the cloud.

Comment: Dharman, thank you for editing my answer and taking out "I hope this helps!" I guess that's one way to get to 18.2k rep.

Comment: Also, SO is not like an encyclopedia. It's literally about technical questions and answers. I hope my answer helped their particular needs despite the technical accuracy of my answer. There is no need for you to go around altering the "style" of the answers in your own perceived way.

Comment: You saved me from 2 more hours of debbugging

Answer (score 2):

I was able to do this by updating the `amplify/backend/function/{function-name}/custom-policies.json` file.

I wanted to be able to call another lambda function that sits behind API Gateway so it looks like this, where "path" is the path to my endpoint and  the "*" are wildcards:

See [aws docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-iam-policy-examples-for-api-execution.html)

```
[
  {
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
      "execute-api:Invoke"
    ],
    "Resource": [
      "arn:aws:execute-api:*:*:*/*/POST/{path}"
    ]
  }
]
```

In the case of sns, I imagine you could use something like the permissions that @Demetrios posted in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64918819/500270)

```
[
  {
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
      "sns:*"
    ],
    "Resource": "*"
  }
]
```

Comment: Thank you, this was helpful.  I didn't even realize that file existed until I saw your comment.  Much easier to add my policies there than in line with the auto-generated ones.